# Import Dashboard in PowerBi Embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Can someone please let me know how to upload PowerBI Dashboard to PowerBi embedded and display the same in web page. I uploaded pbix file but not sure how to go about dashboard

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following resources:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started/

The first of them contains an example of web app with embedded power bi dashboard.
In the sample web app you can see what NuGet packages to reference for power bi embedded, js file to add as well as provisioning and MVC objects. Following the example is reasonably straightforward.

EDIT

I'd also recommend to follow the following GitHub link which contains an updated example based on the latest version of the NuGet packages.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/blob/master/EmbedSample/Controllers/DashboardController.cs#L69

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you can only embed reports, powerbi embedded doesn't support embedding dashboards. However you may be able to achieve what you want by using the PowerBI API, take a look at the following link [powerbi-developer-integrate-tile](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-tile/)